# How to call WordPress PHP file using external js file

Tags: php, functions, jquery, wp-blog-header.php

I have added custom PHP file in WordPress directory and added following line to use WordPress functions:

```
require ('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Now I am able to use WordPress functions but unable call this file from javascript in ajax.

When I removed following line then I am able to call this file:

```
require ('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Please suggest how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Why unable to call? Also, have you reviewed this? https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: Please post the contents of wp-blog-header.php. You bring up ajax out of nowhere it seems because you are not providing enough information to help you. Also, be clearer on what you are doing, I have to assume you put require() inside a functions.php file, but you are not clear on this. Also, if true, use require_once() 99.9% of the time. Post the content of your the js file with the ajax code.